# WPF Binding in columns not working

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a list ob object like this:

```
public class Device : ObjectBase
{
    private int _DeviceNbr;

    public int DeviceNbr
    {
        get { return _DeviceNbr; }
        set { _DeviceNbr = value; }
    }

    private string _DeviceName;

    public string DeviceName
    {
        get { return _DeviceName; }
        set { _DeviceName = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<State> _DeviceStates;

    public ObservableCollection<State> DeviceStates
    {
        get { return _DeviceStates; }
        set { _DeviceStates = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}

public class State: ObjectBase
{
    public int StateNbr { get; set; }

    private string _stateType;

    public string StateType
    {
        get { return _stateType; }
        set { _stateType = value; }
    }

    private int _value;

    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

which I need to bind to a Datagrid. 
My approach is to create a customDataGrid which looks like this:

```
public class CustomGrid : DataGrid
{
    public ObservableCollection<ColumnConfig> ColumnConfigs
    {
        get { return GetValue(ColumnConfigsProperty) as ObservableCollection<ColumnConfig>; }
        set { SetValue(ColumnConfigsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnConfigsProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("ColumnConfigs", typeof(ObservableCollection<ColumnConfig>), typeof(CustomGrid), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnColumnsChanged)));

    static void OnColumnsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataGrid = d as CustomGrid;
        dataGrid.Columns.Clear();

        dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Nbr", Binding = new Binding("DeviceNbr") });
        dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Device", Binding = new Binding("DeviceName") });

        foreach (var columnConfig in dataGrid.ColumnConfigs.Where(c => c.IsVisible))
        {
            var column = new DataGridTextColumn()
            {
                Header = columnConfig.ColumnHeader,
                Binding = new Binding("DeviceStates")
                {
                    ConverterParameter = columnConfig.ColumnName,
                    Converter = new DeviceStateConverter(),
                    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
                    Mode =BindingMode.TwoWay
                }
            };
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
        }
    }
}

public class DeviceStateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is ObservableCollection<State> DeviceStates && parameter != null)
        {
            var DeviceState = DeviceStates.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StateType == parameter.ToString());

            if (DeviceState != null)
                return DeviceState.Value;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The ViewModel looks like this:

```
 public class MainViewModel : ObjectBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Device> _Devices;

    public ObservableCollection<Device> Devices
    {
        get { return _Devices; }
        set { _Devices = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ColumnConfig> _columnConfigs;

    public ObservableCollection<ColumnConfig> ColumnConfigs
    {
        get { return _columnConfigs; }
        set { _columnConfigs = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }


    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Devices = new ObservableCollection<Device>();

        _columnConfigs = new ObservableCollection<ColumnConfig>()
        {
            new ColumnConfig(){ ColumnHeader = "On", ColumnName = "On", ColumnWidth= 100, IsVisible= true},
            new ColumnConfig(){ ColumnHeader = "Off", ColumnName = "Off", ColumnWidth= 100, IsVisible= true}

        };

        for ( int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            _Devices.Add(new Device()
            {
                DeviceNbr = i,
                DeviceName = "Device " + i.ToString(),
                DeviceStates = new ObservableCollection<State>()
                {
                    new State() { StateType = "On", Value= i},
                    new State() { StateType = "Off", Value= i+1}
                }

            });
        }

        OnPropertyChanged("ColumnConfigs");
        OnPropertyChanged("Devices");

    }

    public void TestStateChange ()
    {

        Devices[2].DeviceName = "Device X";
        Devices[2].DeviceStates[0].Value = 5;
       // OnPropertyChanged("Devices");
    }


}
```

And the XAML like this:

```
<local:CustomGrid
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ColumnConfigs="{Binding ColumnConfigs}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Devices, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Here is the result:

[Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8cTx.png)

Now the problem is that the binding for the Devicesstates does not work.
In the ViewModel is a method called "TestStateChange" where tried to change that state. The state in the DeviceStatesCollection changed like expected but it doesn't reflect to the view. Can someone please provide me some help?

---

UPDATE

The binding works but PropertyChanged Event when changing the value of a state does not fire.

```
public void TestStateChange()
    {
        foreach (var device in Devices)
        {
            foreach (var state in device.DeviceStates)
            {
                state.Value = state.Value + 1;
            }

            device.OnPropertyChanged("DeviceStates");
        }
    }
```

So I have to raise the PropertyChangedEvent on the "parent" collection of the state. That's weird. 
The only think that I can now think of, is to implement an event in the State class and let the parent collection object subscribe to it.

Does someone has a better idea?

Comment: What is `ObjectBase`? Does it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Also you need to set `TwoWayBinding` for your `DeviceName` column.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Yes ObjectBase is just the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation. The DeviceName changes when TestStateChange Method is called.

Comment: ohh, it seems I skipped that part. Did you try setting a breakpoint in the Converter method and observing wether that method is called when the value is changed?

Comment: The Convert Method will not be called when the value changes. I also commented out the ConverterParameter without any success.

Comment: What's the reason for having the DeviceStates in a collection? Are there more than 2 per device? Or: Would it be possible to have two properties instead of one collection for the device states? That would be easier to handle than this.

Comment: We have different types of devices with different amount and different types of states. So in an other part of the application you can choose the Device type and based on your choice you will get this list.

Comment: If there is an other way to flatten down the data an preserve binding please let me know.

Comment: ah damn it. In that case - which version of Visual Studio are you using? The newer ones have a build-in WPF debug helper where you can drill into the visual tree during runtime and look at the objects behind it. You could then manipulate a stat from there, see if it changes correctly from either direction.

Comment: VS 2017 Community. I will give it a try.

Comment: ah, not sure about that. You could also try a tool like WPF Snoop.

Comment: Do you really need this custom Grid in place? All that code can be replaced with simple `XAML` and standard `DataGrid`. Define the columns in xaml and place appropriate `DataTemplates` in `CellTemplate` for each `Column`. And with standard `DataGrid` you will have your Binding working.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I don't know how to achieve this. Depending on the type of the device there will be a different number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

If your `State` object implements INotifyPropertyChanged (which all your bindable data objects should), and if your datagrid column binds directly to a State object (i.e. via a binding path that contains an index) then your UI will update as you expect.

You could subscribe to the `State` property change events from the parent `Device` object and then re-notify from there, but that is a long winded way to do it and means that you have to subscribe to the CollectionChanged event of the `ObservableCollection` that contains the `State` objects so that you can attach/unattach from the PropertyChange event on each `State` object (sometimes this will be the only way, but avoid it if you can).

Comment: _"If your State object implements INotifyPropertyChanged (which all your bindable data objects should), and if your datagrid column binds directly to a State object (i.e. via a binding path that contains an index) then your UI will update as you expect."_  Could you please tell me how this can be done in my case?